# Angular 9 refreshToken without httpInterceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, refresh-token, behaviorsubject

The last few days I dealt with the following problem:

I want to implement one Function as a boolean Observable to establish Authentication in my webapp.
The Problem is: Im using Websockets as well as Http Requests.

Websockets cannot be interceped, not even the initial handshake.
This is why I wanted to refresh the Auth Token with a http request right away within
the authentication check observable pipe.

This is the Model of my AuthTokens:
[AuthToken Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCViA.png)

This is the Constructor of the Auth Service:
[Auth Service Member Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIdnt.png)

And these are the Functions that I want to use to continuously establish authentication
on a user that is active on the page:

[refreshing Tokens & check Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YioUA.png)

**isAuthenticated$()** is supposed to be returned by the canActivate() function of an AuthGuard to
indicate that a user is indeed authenticated.

**redeemRefreshToken()** is supposed to launch the httpRequest to request a new token if the
current one is expired.

The current problem is that the httpRequest doesn't actually fire. It Jumps into the
redeemRefreshToken()-function, logs a message, but probably some subscription is left out.

Anyone got any suggestions?